# Can't install Hamachi on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, vpn

I've tried to install Hamachi in Ubuntu 14.04 but seem to have no progress.

The installation:

```
wget https://secure.logmein.com/labs/logmein-hamachi-2.1.0.119-1.i486.rpm
```

Result:

```
-----2014-10-03 00:49:39-----
https://secure.logmein.com/labs/logmein-hamachi-2.1.0.119-1.i486.rpm
Resolving secure.logmein.com (secure.logmein.com)... 77.242.192.193
Connecting to secure.logmein.com (secure.logmein.com)|77.242.192.193|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2014-10-03 00:49:40 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Answer (score 3):

Go here:
https://secure.logmein.com/welcome/labs/?iislang=en-US&lang=en#HamachiforLinux

Click "Learn more" and download the appropriate version then double-click it. For GUI do this (after installing Hamachi):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/haguichi 
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install haguichi
```

Source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Hamachi